# html table in a tooltip asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I know you have to set the title attribute for a control to display tooltip in asp.net mvc. 
How do I display a table in the tooltip? I set the title attribute to have the following :

```
<table><tr><th>Name</th><th>Number</th></tr><tr><td>Jake</td><td>2334</td></tr></table>
```

But it doesn't display a table, it is displayed as it is, please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can you use the tooltip plugin of jQuery UI http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#custom-content.